# Web application response time slow with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I’ve been developing web applications in Visual Studio 2013 for a year or more with no problems, however I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 also and started using it but the response time from web applications is significantly slower under VS 2015 than VS 2013.

We are talking about a 150ms response time under VS 2013 vs a 1400ms response time for the same request under VS 2015. I am using the default local copy of IIS Express that comes with Visual Studio.

CPU usage is fairly low with both versions. But during the request the CPU spikes to an average of about 8% usage with VS 2013 whereas with VS 2015 an average of about 15% usage.

I already have Browser Link disabled.

I am using Chrome but Firefox also has the same issue.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Are there other things I can disable to improve performance when using VS 2015?

Comment: Same and I wrote up a question which might be related - http://superuser.com/questions/959046/chrome-spending-a-lot-of-time-stalled  Are you using Chrome?  Have you tried other browsers?  Or is this something different?

Answer (score 0):

vs 2015 is by default running some more diagnostic tools that may affect your response, but i think you can disable them.
it should not affect the final project.

also some extensions like web essentials ware not optimized yet for vs 2015
make sure you got the latest version